# autoref pointing to a wrong place when dealing with subequations

Tags: math-mode, hyperref, luatex

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Some Text
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    d(k_{a},k_{b})=
\end{equation}

Some Text

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:2}
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:2-1}
    s(k_{a},k_{b})
\end{equation}

Some Text

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:2-2}
    d(k_{a},k_{b})=
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

Some Text \\

\autoref{eq:1}.
\autoref{eq:2}.
\autoref{eq:2-1}.
\autoref{eq:2-2}.
\end{document}
```

2-1, and 2-2 point into wrong places despite having the correct name.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: [With very few exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5001), `hyperref` should always be **loaded last**. To wit, if you load `hyperref` *after* rather than before `mathtools` and recompile the test document, clicking on the hyperlinks will take you to the correct locations.

Comment: @Mico Thank you, that solved the problem.